# How to use TLS and SHA-2 certificates in Domino Web Service Consumer

Tags: web-services, lotus-domino

As many others, we have got bitten by the lack of TLS and SHA-2 support in IBM Domino.

Our application relies heavily on consuming web services that require authentication using certificates. And everything worked fine until last week. Then, one of the providers started requesting SHA-2 certificates for authentication and the other started requesting TLS instead of SSS v3.

Our current solution uses Java web consumers, similar to this:

```
ServiceBinding stub = new ServiceLocator().getWebService(portAddress);
stub.setSSLOptions(PortTypeBase.NOTES_SSL_SEND_CLIENT_CERT + PortTypeBase.NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_SITE_CERTS);
```

Certificates are kept in the server's keyring.

How can we use SHA-2 certificates and TLS with Domino web consumers?

I tried importing the certificates in Java truststore / keystore and using code like this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/to/keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pwd);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pwd");
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs","com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
```

but it didn't seem to work. I am still debugging the code in order to find the exact cause.

But what to do with TLS? Is is possible to use Apache / Nginx as some kind of proxy for web service authentication?

Or is our only option to write web service consumers as standalone Java applications and call them from Notes?

Thanks,

Sasa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to solve both SHA-2 and TLS issues by using an Apache reverse proxy. We first tried with forward proxy, but it didn't work.

In the working solution, our Domino web service consumer first contacts the Apache reverse proxy using SSL, but without any authentication. Then Apache contacts the web service provider using the certificate that Domino used previously.

After Apache and web service provider finished handshake and authentication, it is free for the web service consumer in Domino to do its stuff.

As it turns out, it was rather easy to set up. You'll need an Apache server (obviously), we installed our in a CentOS virtual machine.

The configuration you need to do is quite simple and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    # Turn off forward proxy
    ProxyRequests Off

    # Communication with Domino is using SSL, so we need SSL support   
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

    # This is necessary for authentication to work.
    SSLProxyEngine On
    # This is Domino certificate including private key saved as unecrypted pem file.
    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/domino-cert.pem
    # This is list of CA certificates necessary to authenticate the provider.
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/provider-cert.pem

    # Redirection rules are in this case very simple - redirect everything that comes
    # to the proxy to the web service provider address.
    ProxyPass / https://ws.provider.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://ws.provider.com/

    # Allow only connections from Intranet.
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 172.20.20.0/24
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Just a few things to mention here:

- You should be able to use certificate and key installed by default with Apache, as they are only used to secure communication between the Domino and the proxy.
- Domino key and certificate must be in unencrypted pem format. Use openssl to convert if necessary. If you should get error message about missing or encrypted private key, open your pem certificate and confirm that it includes **`RSA`** in lines `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. openssl sometimes generates certificate without the `RSA` and then Apache won't be able to use it.

That concludes the Apache configuration. The only thing that remains is to modify the web service consumer - find in your code the line where you set endpoint address, something like
`https://ws.provider.com/ws/getTemperature`
and change it to
`https://proxy.mycompany.com:8443/ws/getTemperature`

And that's it. We now have working solution for using Domino web services together with TLS and SHA-2 certificates. And we can calmly wait for IBM to implement support for this in Domino.

Answer (score 0):

SHA2 works but TLS for Windows and Unix use tips
I guess in the context of Poodle TLS not SHA-2 is critical, but anyway here is how to get SHA-2 working with Domino 9 without IBM HTTP.
http://www.infoware.com/?p=1592
TLS is NOT SOLVED by this only SHA-2.
For Windows use IHS integration
For unix look at this link http://blog.darrenduke.net/darren/ddbz.nsf/dx/here-is-a-freely-available-vm-to-reverse-proxy-domino-shoot-the-poodle.htm

Regards
Mats

Comment: Hi, at this moment, TLS support is much more important for us than SHA-2, as all of our web service providers turned off SSL3 support in a matter of days. We are currently investigating a solution with an Apache forward proxy that is doing 2-way SSL authentication with the providers. Not working at the moment, but hopefully we'll be able to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid having to change your addresses to use a different port.

The way I solved this was to use IBM HTTP Server (IHS) installed with Domino 9 Server (you have to choose IBM HTTP Server from the Custom installation screen).  IHS is a version of Apache with a Domino HTTP handler.  You can install your TLS certificates on the IHS/Apache server, and will proxy to the Domino server on-the-fly.  So you don't even have to change your URLs.

Here are some instructions from IBM:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039743&aid=1

It shows you how to Create Signing Requests (CSRs) using IKEYMAN and store the certificate in Domino.

In the domino\ihs\conf\ **domino.conf** file, edit by uncommenting the lines as per below and add the VirtualHost nodes:

```
# IPv4 support:
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
# Uncomment the following line for IPv6 support on Windows XP or Windows
# 2003 or later. Windows IPv6 networking must be configured first.
# Listen [::]:80
...
Listen 0.0.0.0:443
## IPv6 support:
#Listen [::]:443

#default vhost for Domino HTTP:
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName "${DOMINO_SERVER_NAME}"
  DocumentRoot "${DOMINO_DOCUMENT_ROOT}"      
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName "${DOMINO_SERVER_NAME}"
  DocumentRoot "${DOMINO_DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
  SSLEnable
  #SSLProtocolDisable SSLv2
  #SSLProtocolDisable SSLv3
</VirtualHost>
KeyFile d:/keys/myserver.kdb
SSLDisable
#
```

Remember to add `HTTPIHSEnabled=1` to notes.ini when all the domino.conf modifications are done.  Then watch the Domino console for any errors during HTTP Start due to domino.conf.  You can also add `HTTPIHSDebugStartup=1` to notes.ini to get a bit of debug info during HTTP IHS startup.

Comment: Why the down vote?  At least explain.  This solution is clean.